# How to use recursion to give the minimum integer in a list using python?

Tags: python, list, recursion, user-input

I am trying to write a recursive function called `my_minimum` that receives a list of integers as parameter and returns the minimum stored in the list. I am able to get the user to input integers separated by a space. However, it gives me a number totally unrelated to what I am trying to achieve.

For example if user list was: `67 89 45 34 23 3 45 67 78`, it should give me give me 3 instead of 23.

```
def my_minimum(A, n):
    # if size = 0 means whole list
    # also if it has been traversed
    if (n == 1):
        return A[0]
    return min(A[n - 1], my_minimum(A, n - 1))

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_string= input("Enter a list element separated by space: ")
    A  = input_string.split()
    n = len(A)
    print(my_minimum(A, n))
```

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. `"23"` is before `"3"` lexicographically. If you want to compare them numerically, convert them to ints.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? You wouldn't normally use recursion for this.

Comment: No, I am just trying to brush up on my recursion skills and decided to try it on a simple problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a string comparison issue, not an issue with your recursion. The string `"3"` compares as greater than the string `"23"`, just like `"B"` sorts after `"AA"` in lexicographical order.

Try converting your strings to integers if you want integer ordering:

```
A  = list(map(int, input_string.split()))
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thought my recursion needed some touching up!